# Kafka SessionWindow with suppress only sends final event when there is a steady stream of input records

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

It appears as though a Kafka Stream with a session window with a grace period and suppression fails to output a final event if there is no constant stream of input records.

**Context:** We are using change data capture (CDC) to monitor changes to a legacy database. When a user makes changes using the UI, a database transaction will change 1..n tables. Each SQL statement results in a Kafka record. These need to be aggregated in order to create one "trigger record" which is used to start an expensive process. The process should be started within a second of the transaction in the legacy database being committed. There are only a handful of users working with the old application, and so there can be significant amount of time between transactions.

We have a Kafka Stream application which uses a session window and an inactivity gap of 400ms in order to aggregate the incoming records that share the same key (the transaction ID), and output the trigger record.

We have a working solution but the trigger record is only written to the output topic so long as other transactions are running in order to generate a steady stream of incoming records. **We need the window to close and the trigger record to be written, even if there are no further input records.**

Working code is here: https://github.com/maxant/kafka-data-consistency/blob/714a44689fd48aa28b05b855638ac7ed50dd5ee9/partners/src/main/java/ch/maxant/kdc/partners/ThroughputTestStream.java#L65

Here is a summary of that code:

```
      stream.groupByKey()
            .windowedBy(SessionWindows.with(Duration.ofMillis(400)).grace(Duration.ofMillis(0)))
            .aggregate(...)
            .suppress(Suppressed.untilWindowCloses(Suppressed.BufferConfig.unbounded()))
            .toStream((k,v) -> k.key())
            .to("throughput-test-aggregated");
```

Initially I had no suppression and no grace period.
Using just the default configuration, I always received a final event for the window containing all the aggregated records, but it was taking up to 6 seconds after the 400ms window, which is too long for us to wait.

In order to reduce the latency and speed things up, I set CACHE_MAX_BYTES_BUFFERING_CONFIG to 1, but that caused an output record after each aggregation, rather than just a single output record.

I introduced the suppression (and with it, a grace period of 0ms), in order to ensure that only one output record is created.

**The problem now is that I only receive an output record, if new input records arrive after the window closes (regardless of their key).**

The test creates 10 input records all with the same key, 10ms apart, all within 100ms. It then rests for 3 seconds, allowing me to shut it off after one group of ten records. I expect to receive one output record, but none arrives, unless I leave the test running, to create a second group of input records. This problem is reproducible.

I have read the following articles but cannot find anything which describes what I am seeing, namely that the final record is only sent to the output topic once additional records (regardless of key) are processed.

- https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-streams-take-on-watermarks-and-triggers/
- https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-328%3A+Ability+to+suppress+updates+for+KTables
- https://kafka.apache.org/10/documentation/streams/developer-guide/config-streams.html

**What do I have to change so that the final record is sent to my output topic, even if no further records are processed?**

(Using Kafka 2.4.1 with client and server on Linux)

Comment: `It appears as though a Kafka Stream with a session window with a grace period and suppression fails to output a final event if there is no constant stream of input records.` --  this is by design.

Comment: Hi @Matthias do you know if it is documented and what work arounds are available?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58571651/suppress-triggers-events-only-when-new-events-are-received-on-the-stream

Comment: Related to and would be resolved by https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-424%3A+Allow+suppression+of+intermediate+events+based+on+wall+clock+time

Comment: one solution: send synthetic records into the stream every X milliseconds which can be filtered out, but because they are constantly arriving, the last window will be published to the sink topic.

Answer (score 4):

**Update** : I have an error in topology, fixed

I had the same exactly same problems as you when using suppress, and it's expected behavior. Because suppress only support emit buffered records using stream time not wall-clock time, if you stop getting new records, stream time will be freeze and `Suppress` will not emit the last suppressed window.

The solution I used is to write a custom suppress using Processor API (use a Transfomer so you can use DSL to send supprssed record downstream) with a state store used as a buffer, then check what windows should be flush (or emit) to downstream processor whenever there is a new record come in or after a time interval has passed (using a `WALL_CLOCK_TIME` punctuate).

The transfomer would look like this:

```
public class SuppressWindowTransformer implements Transformer<Windowed<String>, String, KeyValue<Windowed<String>, String>> {
    private ProcessorContext context;
    private Cancellable cancellable;
    private KeyValueStore<Windowed<String>, String> kvStore;
    @Override
    public void init(ProcessorContext context) {
        this.context = context;
        kvStore = (KeyValueStore) context.getStateStore("suppressed_windowed_transaction");
        cancellable = context.schedule(Duration.ofMillis(100), PunctuationType.WALL_CLOCK_TIME, timestamp -> flushOldWindow());
    }

    @Override
    public KeyValue<Windowed<String>, String> transform(Windowed<String> key, String value) {
        kvStore.put(key, value);//buffer (or suppress) the new in coming window
        flushOldWindow();
        return null;
    }

    private void flushOldWindow() {
        //your logic to check for old windows in kvStore then flush

        //forward (or unsuppressed) your suppressed records downstream using ProcessorContext.forward(key, value)
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        cancellable.cancel();//cancel punctuate
    }
}
```

And in your Stream DSL:

```
stream.groupByKey()
            .windowedBy(SessionWindows.with(Duration.ofMillis(400)).grace(Duration.ofMillis(0)))
            .aggregate(...)//remove suppress operator and write custom suppress using processor API
            .toStream()
            .transform(SuppressWindowTransformer::new, "suppressed_windowed_transaction")
            .to("throughput-test-aggregated");
```

Comment: This looks like building a window on top of a window :-) Could I not leave the window and suppress out and just implement my own window check in the transformer?

Comment: Of course you could, that is more elegant approach, simplify Topology a lot, it's also easier to write tests.

Comment: This solution does not work because the transformer is not called for the last window. In my solution I have a mapValues after the supress, and it too doesn't get called. Because the transformer doesn't get called, the store contains no records and so while punctuate does call flushOldWindow, I still get no results for the last window, until new records arrive on the source stream.

Comment: @AntKutschera Sorry, I have an error in Topology, should have removed the suppressed operator, updated the answer, here we write a custom suppress logic use the Transformer